# Sort entire *ngFor by property in inner *ngFor

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table that is using two `*ngFor` expressions. I have created a pipe that allows sorting /ordering based on object properties. However, I do not know how or if I can sort an outer *ngFor based on a property in an inner *ngFor.

This is the HTML I am using:

```
<table *ngIf="option == 'Document Type'">
  <tr>
    <th class="modalheader">Sources</th>
    <th class="modalheader">Systems</th>
  </tr>
  <table *ngFor="let doctype of doctypes | sort: 'source.Title'" style="width: 200%; margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr *ngFor="let source of doctype.Source;">
    <td style="width:50%;">{{source.Title}}</td>
    <td>
      {{doctype.System.Title}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</table>
```

I have attached an example with actual data and my pipe used for sorting.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[field] < b[field]) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
      return array;
    }

}
```

```css
.modalheader {
  background-color: #00539B;
  color: white !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* REVIEW: ADDED FOR TABLE */
  font-size: 1.46em;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 50%;
}

.docs {
  width: 99%;
  /* margin-top: 25px; */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="modalheader">Sources</th>
    <th class="modalheader">Systems</th>
  </tr>
  <table style="width: 200%; margin-top: 0px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">Lafayette Savings Bank</td>
      <td>
        Nautilus
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 200%; margin-top: 0px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">United Bancorp</td>
      <td>
        Nautilus
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 200%; margin-top: 0px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">Old National</td>
      <td>
        FIS
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</table>
```

Is this possible to do and if so, how?

Comment: This is not meant to be a direct answer to your question, but I think that you'd be better off sorting your data in your component, and then keeping the display logic to simple iteration. You'd get more maintainable code - both easier to understand, and easier to unit test.

Comment: What do you expect from your code? What if inner ngFor has 5 items. What exact `i` will be applied for sort in parent ngFor?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I see what you mean. In that case, the main *ngFor loop should be sorted in ascending order by `source.Title`. I can sort by `source.Title` for the inner loop but not the entire loop currently. That is what I am trying to achieve.